# Mlogit macro with dummy variables

Tags: regression, stata, stata-macros

I am new to Stata and macros.

I am trying to loop over several variables to generate estimates from the `mlogit` command and then save them in datasets. That portion is working well.

The problem I have is a categorical variable that I need to split into dummy variables:

```
global mypath "/Volumes/NO NAME/Dissertation/Data/AIM 2"
use "$mypath/AIM 2 DATA"
global SES "sesq2 sesq3 sesq4 sesq5"

/*regression*/

foreach xvar in age_median female marital ethnicity literacy $SES poor_health physical_median mental_median facility_fee time_clinic {
    mlogit trauma_main `xvar', b(5) vce(cluster ea_id) rrr
    parmest, saving("$mypath/multi_`xvar'.dta", replace)
}
```

I thought that by setting `SES` as a global variable, the loop would treat that as one set of variables, but I was mistaken. The code loops over every variable in `$SES` so I end up with each dummy variable regressed onto `trauma_main` separately, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to "tell" Stata to treat the dummy variables as one block? Additionally, I know that I could do `i.SES` and using that does work fine, but the reference group that is used is not the one that I want. I have googled how to set the reference group for something like `i.var`, but I am coming up with nothing useful, likely because I am using the wrong search terms.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Maggie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to split your categorical variable into dummies. You can use the factor variables notation (`i.`) instead. This is documented in `help fvvarlist`. With factor variables, a change of the reference category is straightforward.

Here is an example. The *site* variable has three categories. By default *site = 1* is the reference category for the categorical variable:

> webuse sysdsn1, clear
>
> foreach v in age male i.site {
>       mlogit insure `v'
>   }

With `ib` you can set the reference category to any desired level. If you want *site = 2* as the reference, you can do the following:

> foreach v in age male ib2.site {
>       mlogit insure `v'
>   }

Answer (score 0):

[Stata's documentation for the `foreach` command](http://stata.com/help.cgi?foreach) indicates that it would work without the global macro, i.e.

```
. foreach xvar in age_median female marital ethnicity literacy "sesq2 sesq3 sesq4 sesq5" poor_health physical_median mental_median facility_fee time_clinic {
```

If you want to do it using a global macro, you'll need to use compound double-quotes to define a macro that includes quote marks:

```
. global SES `""sesq2 sesq3 sesq4 sesq5""'
```